# Fluid Design of Video Player for video.js(mobile)v

Tags: html, mobile

I have created a page for video viewing on mobile using video.js.
Code Snippet:

```
<video id="intro_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"  controls poster='img' preload="auto" data-setup="{}">
 <source src="v.webm" type="video/webm" /> 
 <source src="v..ogg" type="video/ogg" /> 
 <source src="v.mp4" type="video/mp4" />  
       </video>
```

The problem I am facing is it it takes default width and height.If I specify height and width in CSS it still overrides .

I want to have a solution for this where it takes width and height using fluid design.

I used this css solution:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
#intro_video,#video_wrap {height:640px;
                 width:992px}

#intro_video_html5_api{height:640px;
                 width:992px}
}

/* VERTICAL TABLET LAYOUT: 768px - 991px
----------------------------------------------------------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
#intro_video,#video_wrap {height:480px;
                 width:640px}
#intro_video_html5_api{height:480px;
                 width:640px}
}




/* WIDE MOBILE LAYOUT: 480px - 767px
----------------------------------------------------------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    #intro_video {height:320px;
                 width:480px}
 #intro_video_html5_api   {height:320px;
                 width:480px}
}
```

but it has not helped me.